# Error While Trying to Use Vector to Implement Stack

Tags: c++, stack

I'm trying to create a stack using a vector, but I can't seem to get it to work... Here is my code:

```
#ifndef _STACK_VEC_TPT_H_
#define _STACK_VEC_TPT_H_
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

// abstract stack class implemented using vector
template<class T>
class abs_stack_vec {
public:
    // pushes an element onto the top of the stack. 
    // grows the vector if needed.
    virtual void push(const T& elem)=0;

    // pops an element from the top of the stack.
    // does nothing if the stack is empty.
    virtual void pop()=0;

    // returns the value of the top element on the stack.
    // throws domain_error if the stack is empty.
    virtual const T& top()=0;

    // returns the number of elements currently on the stack.
    virtual unsigned size() const=0;
};

// the following class inherits from the abstract stack class
// using its own implementation of a vector
// you must implement the abstract methods push, pop, and top.
template<class T>
class mystack_vec: public abs_stack_vec<T> {
public:
    unsigned size() const {return _size;}

    // method used for growing vector when size equals capacity
    // and need to add more elements
    void grow() {
        T* temp = new T[_size * 2];
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < _size; ++i) {
            temp[i] = _values[i];
        }
        delete[] _values;
        _values = temp;
        _capacity = _size * 2;
    }

    // default constructor
    mystack_vec() {
        _capacity = 5;
        _size = 0;
        _values = new T[_capacity];
    }

    // pushes an element onto the top of the stack. 
    // grows the vector if needed.
    void push(const T& elem)
    {
        if (_size == _capacity)
        {
            grow();
        }
        _values[_size] = (elem);
        ++_size;
    }

    // pops an element from the top of the stack.
    // does nothing if the stack is empty.
    void pop()
    {
        if (_size != 0)
        {
            delete _values[_size];
            --_size;
        }
    }

    // returns the value of the top element on the stack.
    // throws domain_error if the stack is empty.
    const T& top() 
    {
        if (_size == 0)
        {
            throw domain_error("The stack is empty!");
        }
        else
        {
            return _values[_size];
        }
    }

    //destructor
    ~mystack_vec() {
        delete[] _values;
    }

    // TO-DO: YOU MUST IMPLEMENT THE FOLLOWING METHODS:
    // PUSH, POP, TOP


    // END OF TO-DO
private:
    T *_values; // array !!
    unsigned _size, _capacity;
};
#endif
```

Trying this method I get the error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Lab 3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  tester.cpp
1>c:\users\jaysen\documents\data structures\lab 3\lab 3\stack_vec_tpt.h(72): error C2541: 'delete' : cannot delete objects that are not pointers
1>          c:\users\jaysen\documents\data structures\lab 3\lab 3\stack_vec_tpt.h(69) : while compiling class template member function 'void mystack_vec<T>::pop(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\jaysen\documents\data structures\lab 3\lab 3\tester.cpp(72) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void mystack_vec<T>::pop(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\jaysen\documents\data structures\lab 3\lab 3\tester.cpp(59) : see reference to class template instantiation 'mystack_vec<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>c:\users\jaysen\documents\data structures\lab 3\lab 3\stack_vec_tpt.h(72): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've also tried including the vector class and using container.push_back() and just push_back, etc. Please help me!

Comment: @juanchopanza: Misleading title. OP doesn't use `std::vector` at all.

Comment: @Zeta good catch! Very misleading indeed.

Comment: I mentioned that I tried using the vector class as well. This is for an assignment where we are supposed to implement a stack using a vector. Everything except the push, pop, and top method was already pre-written and cannot be changed.

Comment: @juanchopanza: std::stack pushes and pops from the back of the underlying container (using back(), push_back() and pop_back() respectively for top(), push() and pop()), so I don't see why std::vector's inability to remove from the front is relevant.

Comment: @rici you are totally right, I don't know what I was thinking. Probably spent too long working with queues today.

Comment: @rici how can I use the container.back(), container.push_back(), and container.pop_back()? I read that it would be the best way to do this, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that `_values[_size]` gives you the last `T` object in your dynamically allocated array, not a pointer. You cannot do `delete _values[_size];` on something that is not a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.

You may, therefore, be tempted to do `delete &_values[_size];` but this is also wrong. Just because you dynamically allocated the entire array with `_values = new T[_capacity];`, doesn't mean you can `delete` the individual elements. You can only deallocate the entire array with `delete[] _values;`.

Now you could use `std::vector` to do it instead, but since you haven't posted the problems you had with that, I can't help you there. However, you are going to too much effort for something that is already provided by the standard:

```
std::stack<int> s;
```

The `std::stack` class is an adapter for other container types. By default, it uses a `std::deque` as its underlying structure, which is much better suited as a stack than `std::vector`.

Comment: I realize this, it's for an assignment and I cannot find a way to pop from the "vector" implementation.

Comment: @JaysenStoudt You'll need to access the element with `operator[]` or `at` and then you could use `pop_back` to remove the element. However, a `std::deque` would be much better for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete int. You can delete int*, but in this code you try to delete int.

See this message:

```
c:\users\jaysen\documents\data structures\lab 3\lab 3\stack_vec_tpt.h(72): error C2541: 'delete' : cannot delete objects that are not pointers
```

Comment: @AI W how can I fix that then? _values is a pointer array, is it not?